# How to reset Azure AD User's temporary password?

Tags: azure, active-directory

I created Active Directory in Azure. I created new user (as global admin) with `*@*.onmicrosoft.com` login. User gets assigned temporary password, that has to be changed on first login.

User is created so that I can use it with Azure AD Connect, to connect on-premise domain with Azure. Until password is reset, it is considered as expired.

Where can I login with that user to reset password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please login into Azure Portal as that user. As a part of the login process, the user will be asked to reset the password because the user is logging in for the first time.